# Replacement for Logitech MX Keys with wired mode support

Tags: usb, keyboards, silent

I own one of the great [Logitech MX Keys keyboards](https://www.logitech.com/de-ch/products/keyboards/mx-keys-for-business.html?sp=5&searchclick=logi). (Dunno what the recent "business" naming is about). I am really fine with it.

**Now, my current employer does not allow wireless keyboards of any kind (Bluetooth or otherwise). It must be wired.**

Although the MX Keys series do have a USB connector, it is strictly for charging *only*. (I checked with their support, and they confirmed this.)

Does anyone have:

- a hack description on how to enable a "Wired Mode" with the MX Keys
- a replacement recommendation with a most similar keyboard

  - flat keys
  - keys with a depression
  - flat design (no or very small inclination)
  - wired mode
  - silent

Comment: What is their concern with wireless keyboards?  I'm guessing they have a security concern, but is it a real or imaginary concern for where you will actually use it?

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate It's a security concern and a valid one. In any case, there's nothing I can do about it, I already asked about whether non-bluetooth, like the MX would be fine, and they are not.

Comment: Sounds good.  Wireless keyboards can have security issues in certain environments.  After quite a bit of searching, I found a versatile keyboard that I think may be a good choice for you (see answer below).  I hope it helps you.

Comment: Would a keyboard that does have a wireless mode be a valid option as long as you do not use that wireless mode? In the case of Bluetooth you have to pair the keyboard, so if you never do that and plug in the keyboard you can prevent an accidental wireless connection. But of course your employer will have to trust you that you never activate wireless mode.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, this would be an option IMHO. Ultimately the employer can not effectively control what kind of keyboard I use, since they do allow external keyboards, and the USB connectors are of course available. In the end, in this case, it's all about me being compliant.

Answer (score 2):

The [Keychron K3 Version 2 Gateron Red Switch keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08LSBTTQX) may be a very good choice for you.

It has a compact flat design, and each key has a curved depression.

It is compatible with Mac, iOS, Windows, and Android.

What's great about this keyboard is that it has a little red toggle switch on one side that allows you to switch between wired (USB) and wireless (Bluetooth) modes.

As a bonus, the keys are backlit, making the keyboard easy to use in a dark environment.

***Note:***

When you click on the above link, it should take you to the ***Gateron Red Switch*** variant of this keyboard.  This is what you want, as it uses quieter components ("switches") for each key.  If the ***Gateron Red Switch*** variant does not appear, after opening the above link, simply click on the appropriate option in the middle of the ensuing page to switch your product choice to the ***Gateron Red Switch*** variant.  (There is also the [Keychron K3 Version 2 Gateron Brown Switch keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08LSJ4RHH), but that keyboard uses louder switch components.)  I think you'll be happiest with the keyboard that uses the Gateron Red Switches.